# How to efficiently draw line graphs in Phaser.js

Tags: graphics, phaser-framework

I want to draw multiple sine curves in [Phaser](http://phaser.io/), but I want to do it efficiently, so that I can animate their movement. Here is what I've tried, but it doesn't look smooth:

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGoWmX?editors=001)

```
var game, DemoState;

//create the game state
function DemoState() {}

DemoState.prototype.create = function() {
  var graphics = game.add.graphics(10, 10);
  window.graphics = graphics;

  window.startTime = game.time.time;
}

DemoState.prototype.update = function(){
  var graphics = window.graphics;
  graphics.clear();

  for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xffffff, 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < 2360; i++) {
      var x = i / 10.0 + (game.time.time - window.startTime) / 50.0;
      var y = Math.sin(x) * 40;

      graphics.lineTo(10 + i, 100 * (j + 1) - y);
    }  
  }
};

// Game Bootstrapper
window.onload = function () {
  game = new Phaser.Game(2400, 1200, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-demo');
  // add the game state to the state manager
  game.state.add('demo', DemoState);
  // and start the game
  game.state.start('demo');
};
```

What is the best way to draw line graphs in Phaser?

Answer (score 1):

After just glancing at your code, I'd suggest you rework the code in `update()`. For loops are generally a no-go since `update()` will execute once before each frame (two nested loops complicate things even further).

A better approach would be to set up a tween (or a bunch of tweens) - and instead of tweening for example a sprite's position, you can tween a numerical value; create and start the tween in `create()`, then just poll the value in `update()`.

Comment: Even if I use tweens, wouldn't I have to loop in `update()` to actually draw all the lines? How does this approach remove the need for `for` loops in `update()`?

Comment: Yes, you would, but you'd have a variable outside of `update()` and you'll set that variable's value using a tween and just read that value in the `update()` loop. Tweens are from what I know one of the most (or the single most) efficient ways to calculate a value over time, regardless of what that value is - a colour, an angle, a position or anything else. Here's a simple example of tweening an angle from 0 to 90 degrees and back - http://phaser.io/sandbox/edit/QJDCrHEi . You can have something similar and just use the value in `update()` the same way it's used in `render()` in the example.

Comment: Right, but that would only address the following line in my code: `var x = i / 10.0 + (game.time.time - window.startTime) / 50.0;`. I would still have to have the multiple for loops to actually draw the lines, which would still be slow, right?